# How do I target multiple frameworks for my windows forms app project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm wondering how I edit my windows form app project to be able to target multiple framework versions, and use #if statements that control the flow of the code depending on which the user has.

There's answers all over the internet - Probably dozens, or hundreds. None of them seem applicable to my project, they all mention blocks of code that don't exist in my project - such as "TargetFramework" tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>WindowsFormsApp1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WindowsFormsApp1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <PublishUrl>C:\Users\Hansens\Desktop\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>2</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This is some data from my csproj file - I haven't found how to edit the "TargetFrameworkVersion" tag to hold multiple framework references, and no "Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" tag anywhere in the whole csproj even though this is referenced everywhere, so I don't have a very good place to start from due to it not looking similar to others - Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the existing .NET Framework Windows Forms project to be the project that contains multiple .NET Framework Target Framework Moniker, or it is often called TFM.

To have correct multiple TFMs, you have to use .NET Core SDK style project by using .NET Core SDK project template instead of .NET Framework Windows Forms project template. These newer .NET Core SDK project templates are always having the first line of the *proj to have marker as related .NET SDK.

To have multiple .NET TFMs, use this `<TargetFrameworks>` tag inside the property group.
The TFMs are separated by semicolon.

For example:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net40;net45</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The answer from Eben is good, but it should clearly mention about the difference in project template kinds, and it's not related to just the csproj at all.

This SDK project template is the way the .NET Core SDK differentiate the project templates across all kinds of supported templates, such as normal/general class libraries/console, with the other main target such as ASP.NET Core SDK project templates and the upcoming .NET Core Windows Forms/WPF SDK.

For example, .NET Core F#,C#,VB projects have this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

For ASP.NET Core, the project has this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Therefore you have to pay attention on the SDK first, then what is the final resulting binaries and the TFMs you want.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I think this gets me a lot closer to where I need to be. Sounds kinda like I'll need to just have two versions for now, or port my project to .net core 3.0 and see where I can go from there - Does this sound about right?

Comment: @StevenHansen yes. Especially .NET Core 3.0, it supports Windows Forms. But you should wait until .NET Core 3.0 reached Release Candidate, with designer support for Windows Forms and WPF. Current .NET Core 3.0 is still in preview.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there are 2 formats for the `csproj` files.  The "traditional", if you will, one that you are displaying and then the newer "sdk" version.  I happen to have an older package that I have yet to update to the newer version that targets multiple framework versions.  The [csproj file](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb.EMail/blob/master/Shuttle.Esb.EMail/Shuttle.Esb.EMail.csproj) contains some conditional processing and the [msbuild file](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb.EMail/blob/master/.build/package.msbuild) that builds the various version has some of the trickery involved.  It should be fairly self-explanatory.  The main issue is that you need some manual editing of the files.

The easiest way to get a newer version is to create a new .net core project.  After that you can edit the, newer version, [csproj file](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb/blob/master/Shuttle.Esb/Shuttle.Esb.csproj) and target even the full .net framework.  The [msbuild file](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb/blob/master/Shuttle.Esb/.build/package.msbuild) is slightly simpler in that the framework itself handles the multiple versions.  Instead of a `TargetFramework` tag there is a `TargetFrameworks` tag for multiple versions.

You only need to target the lowest version supported as the rest should be OK.  You could even only target .net standard.  I target .net 4.6.1, .net standard 2.0, and .net core 2.1 since I have had issues resolving .net standard-only packages.  Perhaps that will change in future.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I believe Eriawan might have extrapolated a bit more but this was helpful nonetheless

Comment: Absolutely fine.  As long as you got the information you needed it's all good! :)